# Julia language: modifying objects

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
function generateinputdistributions! (jointA, jointB)
    rand! (jointA)
    rand! (jointB)
    println (sum (jointB))
    jointA *= (1.0/sum (jointA))
    jointB *= (1.0/sum (jointB))
    println (sum(jointB))
end
```

And I have a few lines of code calling it in another file:

```
generateinputdistributions! (jointA, jointB)
println (sum (jointB))
```

where jointA and jointB have been preallocated. I expected that the third print statement should give an answer of 1 (the second one does). However, it does not, and instead gives the value of the first print statement. Thus, it looks like the jointA in jointA *= (1.0/sum (jointA)) is a local object that is destroyed. Can someone please explain what exactly is going on?

What I want to do is modify jointA and jointB in place (for performance reasons). rand! seems to do its job correctly. I don't understand this behavior of *=.

Answer (score 1):

`jointA *= (1.0/sum (jointA))` will result in the jointA variable containing a new object leaving the old jointA untouched. the reason is that multiplication does not modify it's operands in place. `*=` is the same as saying `= *(...)` After that line jointA contains a different object than before the line. The new object is scoped to the function since it is allocated there and never returned so julia is free to GC it after the function exits.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't really understand why this must be the case. To me (from C/C++ experience), "*=" and " = *" should have (or at least be allowed to have) different meanings. For instance, in C/C++, one can overload the two operators "*" and "*=". When one wants to modify the object in place, one can use "*=", and when one wants a new object, one uses "= *". Basically, "*=" should not just be a syntactic sugar, it should have different meaning in my opinion. Can you shed more light as to why Julia does not do this?

Comment: @MrAlpha: Thanks. From the discussion there, it sounds like if one does jointA[:] *= (1.0/sum (jointA)), one gets the performance associated with not creating a new object (that is, modify the array in place), right?

Comment: No, it creates a new object and copies it. To really do it in place, use the `scale!` function.

Comment: @tholy: ok. Don't you think it would be nicer if there was some sort of operator syntax (such as .*= or *!=) instead of having to use the scale! function?

Comment: The operators *are* functions themselves. It's just that only some of them are blessed with the ability to be used as infix operators. scale! is not really any more or less nice than using a special operator really.

Comment: Of course there is no such thing as being "nicer". I just find the C++ interpretation of "*=" and " = * " very intuitive and clear. Internally, it is still a function even in C++. My point is: why provide a "*="  and "= *" if the two are identical in meaning. Is the reason a mere syntactic sugar?